# Вывести данные с конца

Tags: php

```
$url = "https://www.site/news/rss/";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$items = new SimpleXmlElement($content);

foreach($items -> channel -> item as $item) {
   ...
}
```

Выводит от верха в низ (3,2,1), а как сделать наоборот, чтобы выводил от низа в верх (1,2,3)?

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать [array_reverse()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reverse.php)

```
foreach(array_reverse($items->channel->item) as $item) {
   ...
}
```

либо вместо `foreach` использовать цикл `for` и сделайте `$i--` вместо `$i++`.

Comment: Warning: array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in / on line 9 and Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in / on line 9

Comment: Может  и не самый элегантный способ , но попробуй сначала собрать массив с помощью unshif.foreach($items -> channel -> item as $item) {
   $arr[]=unshift($item);
}

Comment: @Евгения Я же понятия не имею какие данные в каком формате у Вас приходят. Можно просто преобразовать объект в массив. `$your_array = (array)$items->channel->item;`